# History of Talmudic Censorship

Tags: history, product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, censorship

I'm looking for literature on the history of Talmudic censorship. I would prefer the material be in English, but Hebrew is also OK.

Related post: [Talmudic Censorship](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/talmudic-censorship)

Comment: This is about history not Judaism. As a result, it is off topice for this site.

Comment: @sabbahillel But one of the available tags is history?

Comment: Questions about the Hebrew language or about history or news of the Jewish people, Jewish individuals, or the State of Israel, except as related to Judaism, are off-topic. If this question does relate to Judaism, please edit it to indicate how.

Comment: I would say keep open - history of Jewish Law is considered on topic, and the Talmud is a fundamental book of Jewish Law.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/what-was-wrong-with-the-word-talmud?s=1|1.8151

Comment: http://www.jewishhistory.com/PRINTINGTHETALMUD/essays/6.html

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=SgvLkMS81q4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4170-censorship-of-hebrew-books

Comment: One more reason to keep it open - the history of Talmudic censorship has applications to understanding the Talmud, hence it meets the criteria for the exception "except as related to Judaism."

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with sabbahillel's view on this. The question needs editing and clarification to indicate what the goal of the OP is. Otherwise, it's simply history.

Comment: An excellent resource is [_The Talmud: A Biography_](http://www.amazon.com/Talmud-Biography-censored-burned-suppress/dp/1472905946/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451272981&sr=8-1&keywords=talmud+biography) by the Jewsih scholar Dr. Harry Freedman. He addresses the topic of censorship in Part II of his book.

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fit your question’s description:

[The Talmud – A Biography: Banned, censored and burned. The book they couldn't suppress](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1472905946) by [Harry Freedman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Freedman_(author)) and more informations about it [here](http://talmudbiography.com.).